# Tridion UI 2012 Session Preview Web Service not maintaining preview in browser

Tags: dd4t, experience-manager

I am struggling to get Tridion UI 2012 Session Preview working on a DD4T website. I view the website in a browser, click the SDL Tridion logo to enter 'edit' mode, then start editing some content on the page.

Once I edit something and click "Finish editing", the error is displayed in the browser: "An existing connection was closed by the remote host", and the webpage does NOT display the text you just edited. Then when I look at the log file for the Session Preview web service, I see the error "Maximum request length exceeded" - I did this by viewing the svclog file (produced by the Session Preview web service) in the ServiceTraceViewer tool.

Now, I have increased the request-size in the web.config of the Session Preview web service, but I still receive the same error. It seems that I need to make the same change (i.e. increase request-size) to the "consumer" of the Session Preview web service.

What is the consumer of the Session Preview web service? i.e. exactly which config file (.config, .xml , .jar, etc) contains a binding to the Session Preview web service? I need to find this file and increase the request-length in there, as a first step, I think.

It seems that the edit is saved to the Tridion_cm database because F5 shows the edit but the preview does not seem to update without a full refresh.

Also, I have already followed the following blog post (and satisfied all its steps/checks) for our debugging: http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/

Any ideas?

Comment: With that error message I suspect this is related to network / request length as you've mentioned in your post. - could you do some tweaking and see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you update the <binding> and the corresponding <service> tag in the web.config from the ODATA webservice? (Did you adjust the 'maxReceivedMessageSize' AND the 'maxBufferSize'?. See the 'AdustedBindingConfiguration' in my example.)

Answer (score 6):

+1 to John's point and your initial troubleshooting approach.

Try adjusting the Web.config of the Session Preview (OData) webservice again--maybe double it until it works and/or confirm how much content (and maybe multimedia) is used by that page. Or try a smaller page. :-)

This [StackOverflow post points out two settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded), one for ASP.NET and another for IIS 7; multiple users also point out the difference in measurement unit (KB for .NET, but bytes for the IIS setting).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="size-in-KB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="size-in-bytes" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Maybe someone else can fill in the details of what gets sent to Session Preview storage. I'm guessing it's the session-specific page, component presentations, and multimedia but haven't checked to be sure.